# Remove Duplicates of string Based on Pattern

Tags: python

I have a list of URLS in format of `http://WEBSITE.com/XXXXX/YYYYY` where `X` and `Y` are random characters.

How would I have Python only keep the results that have distinct case-insensitive `XXXXX` values? It does not matter if it keeps the `YYYYY` portion?

Comment: If you are on a *nix server you could just shell out from python and do a sort -u listfile | uniq -i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `rsplit()` and then use a `Set`.
`rsplit` is used to split a string by a delimiter, such as '/', and a `set` holds unique elements.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html - rsplit()
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set - set

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can easily shave off the last part of the path:

```
id = "/".join(url.split('/')[:-1]) # split, lose last item, rejoin
```

Then put your IDs on a `set()` to keep them unique:

```
ids = set()
ids.add(id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a set comprehension:

```
values = { url.split("/")[3] for url in url_list }
```